# How to add vowel to arabic letter

Tags: javascript, html, unicode

How to add vowel to arabic letter from unicode/hexentity

for example i have:

- U+FE8F  ( ﺏ ) and want to add this vowel U+FE76 ( ﹶ )  -> ﺏﹶ
- U+FE8F  ( ﺏ ) and want to add this vowel U+FE78 ( ﹸ )  -> ﺏﹸ

I do it by js

```
let s1 = document.createElement('span')
    s1.innerHTML = "&#xFE8F; &#xFE78; or &#xFE8F;&#xFE78;"
    document.querySelector('#text').append(s1)
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Put them next to each other? They seem to combine automatically for me `'ﺏ' + 'ﹷ'` becomes `'ﺏﹷ'` (which looks correct when not using a monospace font)

Comment: @evolutionxbox - To me those look like they're just next to each other (even in a non-monospace font). Neither of the characters seems to be a combining character. I'm guessing (guessing big time) that there are other Unicode code points that define combining versions of these.

Comment: The description of ﺏ is "[ARABIC LETTER BEH ISOLATED FORM](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=FE8F)," which suggests to me it's not meant for combining with other code points. It looks like rendering Arabic correctly [is complicated](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr53/#Overview). If you can't read/write Arabic, I would avoid trying to create combinations without a great deal of study. But hopefully someone who reads and writes Arabic can chime in with useful knowledge.

Comment: Note: ligatures is different from combining characters. What Unicode define as "grapheme cluster" is created by a series of characters, independent if they are combining or not).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi - Good point. I should have said "combining (in a non-technical sense)." I looked into this a while back and wow, it's complicated. :-D (Unicode, not Arabic.)

Comment: *"I do it by js"* You don't want that space between them, for a start. But again, I suspect there's more to it than that.

Comment: thanks for your comments. i forgot inform that i generate the string from java script. i update the question. still don't find the answer. may be i will use CSS to position them.

Comment: @aldrian - *"may be i will use CSS to position them"* Don't do that. Instead, find the right way to write them.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder for me, still not work when put them side by side. yes, i thing using css not the right solution too.. i will search again. thanks

Comment: Just concatenate the string to the vowel (diacritics).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the OP is using the non-joining forms of the Arabic script Unicodes.

Comment: @MohsenAlyafei - As I suspected then. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Arabic script in Unicode has in general five (5) forms of Unicode:

1. General form letter (**the normally used**)
2. (Contextual form) **Isolated** form letter.
3. (Contextual form) **End** form.
4. (Contextual form) **Middle** form.
5. (Contextual form) **Beginning** form.

The Contextual forms have Unicodes from \uFE80.

Examples here:

[image]

[More information here on Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script_in_Unicode)

When working with Arabic Letters (strings) **use the General form (code)** to do your string manipulations. The system takes care and detects the position of the letter within others and creates the right form out of the other 4 forms.

Now, if you start using the other forms. In your case, you have an **Isolated Form** that you want to concatenate to another **Isolated Form** letter it will not join.

An Isolated Form Letter needs a non-isolated form letter to join with.

#### In short, two Isolated Letters will not join and will remain isolated.

##### Here are some code examples:

```js
//============================================
// Isolated Characters Codes
//============================================
console.log("----------- Isolated Letters Not Joining-------------")


let b_isolated = "ﺏ";          // isolated letter code  U+FE8F
let t_isolated = "ﺕ";          // isolated letter code  U+FE95
console.log(b_isolated+t_isolated);  // ﺏﺕ will never join

console.log(b_isolated+'\uFE78');        // ﺏﹸ will never join
console.log(b_isolated+'\uFE76');        // ﺏﹶ will never join



//============================================
// Normal/General Characters
//============================================
console.log("----------- General Letters Joining -------------")

let b_general = "ب"; // code U+0628
let t_general = "ت"; // code U+062A
console.log(b_general+t_general);  // بت  joined


// add normal accents to the normal letter
console.log(b_isolated+'\u064E');        // ﺏَ joined
console.log(b_isolated+'\u064F');        // ﺏُ joined
```

When using Arabic characters use the Unicode range [\u0600 to \u06FF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_(Unicode_block)) with sample here:

[image]

Comment: Sorry for late reply. this is the answer that i miss. thanks, بارك الله فيك